# Set key and from variable in one line

Tags: javascript

I want to set an option in the same line/statement with both the key and value on the same line:

Here's how to do it on multiple lines:

```
var  options = {}
  ,  key = "foo", value = "bar"
  ;
options[key] = value;
myFunction( options ); // object is { "foo" : "bar" }
```

Here's what I want to do:

```
myFunction({key:value}); // object is { "key" : "bar" }
```

Which won't work. Is there a way to do this in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this in one line?

Sure:

```
myFunction((obj = {}, obj[key] = value, obj));
```

This is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) at work here. It evaluates each expression from left to right and returns the value of the last expression. Note that the expression is inside parenthesis `(...)`, otherwise the comma would be interpreted as argument separator.

The disadvantage is that `obj` is *global* and overall it's less readable.

---

Basically, technically it's possible, but you shouldn't do it. There is nothing wrong with doing this in multiple lines and there is no way to use an object literal and set a dynamic key.

Comment: Can you expand a little on the use of the comma inside of the expression?

Comment: I would do:
`myFunction( ((obj = {}) [key] = value, obj) );`

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it doesn't use any extra function calls. :)

Answer (score 3):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/jLURu/)***

You could construct the object using the `new` keyword with a `function`.

```
myFunction(new function(){this[key]=value;});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myFunction( JSON.parse('{"'+key+'":"'+value+'"}') )
```

---

If `key` or `value` contain quotes or characters that need to be escaped then do

```
myFunction( JSON.parse('{'+JSON.stringify(key)+':'+JSON.stringify(value)+'}') )
```

Thanks to Felix and zerkms.

Comment: As long as `key` and `value` don't contain `"`.

Comment: @Felix Kling: `JSON.stringify` them! ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: Doh, of course. Makes the code so much better too :)

Answer (score 0):

My professional opinion is that you should not do that.

Adding multiple tasks to a single expression, line, statement (however you call) makes code readability worse. If you want to express something complicated in a single line, then write a function for it. When you work in a team, sacrificing code readability is not an option. It is hard to develop and maintain unreadable code...

Comment: How Uglifier is relevant to the question about *syntax*? o_O

Comment: It removes all the new line characters, so everything will be in a single line :D It's the goal of the questioner, isn't it? :D

Comment: I'm sure by a "single line" OP meant a "single expression"

Comment: Btw why would anyone do something like that?

Comment: "Btw why would anyone do something like that?" --- because less expressions very often means it's easier to read

Comment: Btw, your answer still doesn't answers the original question

Comment: "because less expressions very often means it's easier to read" - yes and this is not that case.

Comment: Ye I know it is hard to face that you cannot do everything in a single expression...

Comment: What should I see? That people give answer without thinking? Great!

Comment: "yes and this is not that case" --- if only you don't know the special handy syntax for that. Thus why OP has asked the question

Comment: "That people give answer without thinking? Great!" --- they have been thinking. And it's obvious that it doesn't worth using.

Comment: Now it **is** an answer ;-) PS: except the last part: "That's all, that's how programming works.", which is a bit speculative

Comment: I can live with that :D Good night!

Comment: Sorry I had to edit it again, it had not fit in with my current arrogant style... :D

Comment: "Adding multiple tasks to a single expression, line, statement (however you call) makes code readability worse." --- that's not true. `var a = []; a.push(42);` isn't better readable than `var a = [42];` The latter is shorter and much more readable even though a single statement.

Comment: Ye and that's part of the core js. What he is asking is not.

Comment: oh my god. OP **DID NOT KNOW** if there is no elegant way to write it in a single expression thus they asked it. So OP just might not know a particular syntax construction that could express what they want as elegantly as `[42]`

Answer (score 0):

What do you all think of this answer?

```
Object.prototype.set = function(key,value){ this[key] = value; return this };

myFunction( ({}).set( key, value ));
```